# Test mouseover and mouseout events in AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm attempting to test the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events in a D3 directive. Here is the section of code I am attempting to test:

```
var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('svg:g')
  .attr('class', 'node')
  .attr('transform', function(d) {
    return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
  })
  .attr('filter', 'url(' + $location.path() + '#drop-shadow)')
  .on('mouseover', function(d) {
    tooltip.transition()
      .duration(200)
      .style('opacity', 0.75);
    tooltip.html(d.email)
      .style('left', (d3.event.pageX - 50) + 'px')
      .style('top', (d3.event.pageY - 50) + 'px');
    d.scale = 1.5;
    tick();
  })
  .on('mouseout', function(d) {
    tooltip.transition()
      .duration(200)
      .style('opacity', 0);
    d.scale = 1;
    tick();
  })
```

Here is the relevant jasmine code for these specific tests:

```
it('should trigger mouse events', function() {
  element.find('.node').triggerHandler('mouseover');
  element.find('.node').triggerHandler('mouseout');
});
```

The functions that should be called on these mouse events remain red in my code coverage is if they've never been triggered. Any one have an idea as to why this would be?

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://blog.greatrexpectations.com/2015/06/12/faking-mouse-events-in-d3/) has worked out for me:

Using jQuery:

```
beforeEach(function(){
    $.fn.triggerSVGEvent = function(eventName) {
        var event = document.createEvent('SVGEvents');
        event.initEvent(eventName, true, true);
        this[0].dispatchEvent(event);
        return $(this)
    }
})
```

and then in the test:

```
it('should trigger mouse events', function() {
    $(yourSelector).triggerSVGEvent('mouseover');
    $(yourSelector).triggerSVGEvent('mouseout');
})
```